# installation fails microsoft sql server 2008 R2 developers edition

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, failed-installation

I'm having a problem installing MS SQL Server 2008 Dev edition, for quite a while now. No matter what I try:

1. I uninstalled the previous installation;
2. I deleted all folders that where installed and had to do with SQL Server 2008;
3. I cleared my registry using ccleaner;
4. I tried 'fixit' utility from microsoft uninstalling left overs;

It just keeps freaking failing at installing setup support files with this error message:

> TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> Unknown property.
>   .
>
> BUTTONS:
>   OK

I'm totally out of ideas.

Any one has a suggestion for me to look at?

Comment: Voting for a close is fine with me, though, your opinion. But care to share the opinion?

Comment: The close votes are all "offtopic for StackOverflow, move to another site" - two for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) so far and one for Programmers.SE (which IMO is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found that in some cases the Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 x86 (SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi) installation can fail.  In this case, open Registry Editor, navigate to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer and search for the key relating to Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 x86.  Backup the key and delete it from the registry.  The installation should now complete successfully.